# Android : how to capture imageView with top of the bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, surfaceview

I got my Camera working as `SurfaceView`. When I took picture, data saved as bitmap and byte array. And I made the byte array to be saved as jpeg file.

I want to take picture with sticker which is loaded as `ImageView`. Is there any way to take picture (Bitmap or byte array or even jpeg file) with `Imageview` on top of picture?

Comment: Take picture and watermark sticker on that image. 
like https://github.com/vinaygaba/RubberStamp

Comment: Thanks for answer. but I couldn't get thru with that.